# Issues with loading product collection after migrations + Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, migration

I am encountering the following issue after migrating the Magento 1.9.0.1 website to a new server.

I am using a php script that I run using ssh which fetches all the products from database and create a csv. it worked fine on the original site but it throws error on the new server. Below is the error trace printed by magento.

```
a:4:{i:0;s:1793636:"SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_d`
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 )) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('92', '145', '100', '131', '128', '81', '89', '123', '126', '127', '124', '96', '121', '102', '125')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_d`
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('79', '90', '99', '120', '75', '76', '91', '80')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_d`
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 )) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('117', '103', '133', '95', '122', '85', '112', '130', '88', '84', '82', '119', '118', '71', '109', '107', '137', '150', '149', '129', '86', '113', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '87', '114', '97', '98')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_d`
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('104', '105', '93', '94', '77', '78')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0) UNION ALL SELECT `t_d`.`entity_id`, `t_d`.`attribute_id`, `t_d`.`value` AS `default_value`, `t_s`.`value` AS `store_value`, IF(t_s.value_id IS NULL, t_d.value, t_s.value) AS `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_d`
     LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `t_s` ON t_s.attribute_id = t_d.attribute_id AND t_s.entity_id = t_d.entity_id AND t_s.store_id = 1 WHERE (t_d.entity_type_id = 4) AND (t_d.entity_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) AND (t_d.attribute_id IN ('106', '72', '83', '146', '101', '135', '148', '73', '136', '134')) AND (t_d.store_id = 0)";i:1;s:1229:"

#0 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `t_d`.`e...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `t_d`.`e...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `t_d`.`e...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `t_d`.`e...')
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(480): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadAttributes(false, false)
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(874): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->_loadAttributes(false, false)
#9 /var/www/html/shell/exporter-new.php(70): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#10 {main}
```

The code that is throwing this error is this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->load();
```

I couldn't figure out what the issue is. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you upgrade or migrate your existing site from one server to another server then upgrade?

Comment: @brentwpeterson no upgrade has been performed. The site is only moved from one server to the other as it is.

Comment: Have you confirmed that pdo_mysql is loaded?
What is the name of the error that is throw?

Comment: @brentwpeterson I have updated the question with the whole output that I am getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using MariaDB 5.5, upgrading it to the latest version (10.1) sorted this issue. 
I am still not sure why the issue was caused but upgrade seemed to do the trick.